# Does Windows Phone support an external camera flash?

Tags: camera

I wonder if there is any external, more powerful, flash that support Windows Phone?

Comment: Do you mean an external flash drive, or a camera flash? You've tagged your question with unrelated tags that make it difficult to determine what problem you're trying to solve

Comment: Flash seems to be a synonym of Flash Player. Didn't know that but the tag is removed now.

Comment: So do you mean flash memory (like for reading SD cards), or camera flash?

Comment: A camera flash.

Answer (score 2):

At time of writing, there are no phones that have exposed contacts for directly connecting an external flashgun, but this doesn't mean that it's not possible to control the flash wirelessly:

There are ways to [get flashes to fire, without direct communication from a camera](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/34762/21), using an optical slave (which really does just see flash, and fire themselves).

In theory, it should also be possible for someone to make something that controls a flash via Bluetooth (Satechi already make a device that [can control a camera via Bluetooth](http://www.satechi.net/index.php/bluetooth/bluetooth-smart-triggers/satechi-bluetooth-smart-trigger-c-for-iphone-5-c-s-iphone-4s-ipad-mini-ipad-3-samsung-galaxy-siii-siv-note-ii-for-canon-eos-60d-70d-digital-rebel-xt-350d-xti-400d-xsi-450d-xs-1000d-t1i-500d-t2i-550d-t3i-60))